# como comparar horas e dizer se o estabelecimento está fechado ou aberto e retornar uma mensagem Json

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Alguma me ajude... Agradeço.É o seguinte eu tenho uma Api com Php + Sql e me retorna os dados em Json. Nos meus dados tem dois campos openRestaurante e closeRestaurante,esses dados são cadastrados no banco em formato de horas, horas de abertura de um estabelecimento e a hora que fecha o estabelecimento como posso fazer essa comparação de horas e me retornar apenas a mensagem de aberto ou fechado no meu Json em vez de me retornar as horas cadastradas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
# dentro do seu while
$statusRestaurante = 'fechado';

# guarda o timestamp da hora que abre
$openTime  = new DateTime($result['openRestaurante']);
$openRestaurante = $openTime->getTimestamp();
# guarda o timestamp da hora que fecha
$closeTime = new DateTime($result['closeRestaurante']);
$closeRestaurante = $closeTime->getTimestamp();
# agora
$nowTime            =  new DateTime(date("H:i"));
$now = $nowTime->getTimestamp();
# se agora for maior ou igual a hora que abre e agora for menor ou igual a hora que fecha
if ( ($now >= $openRestaurante) && ($now <= $closeRestaurante) )
{
    $statusRestaurante = 'aberto';
}
# echo $statusRestaurante;
$out .= '"statusRestaurante": "'.$statusRestaurante.'",';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas, queria perguntar se eu colocar essas linhas de código dentro do meu while do meu código ele me retornaria já aberto ou fechado ? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode realizar operações de soma e subtração de datas utilizando as classes DateTime e DateInterval do php.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php

E então você poderá comparar se a hora atual precede a hora de abertura ou se sucede a hora de fechamento, assim indicando que o restaurante está fechado.

Espero ter ajudado.